# How to use Intents in Gluon project?

Tags: gluon, gluon-mobile

I would like to take or select a picture, in order to use it for an `ImageView`, like it is shown here: http://gluonhq.com/handling-android-native-activities-like-a-pro/.

The problem that I'm facing is that when the according `Intent` is started, my app gets closed, the camera / galery shows up, and I'm not able to get the result of the intent, i.e. after taking / selecting a picture my app is restartet, and shows the `HomeView`.

android version 4.1.1
javafxports 8.60.6 (also tried 8.60.7)

**UPDATE:**

On Android 5.0 and javafxports 8.60.7 it is working as expected. Just had to add the lines which check if storageDir exists:

```
 private File createImageFile() throws IOException {
    String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
    String imageFileName = "JPEG_" + timeStamp + "_";

    File storageDir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
    if (!storageDir.exists()) {
        storageDir.mkdirs();
    }
    return File.createTempFile(imageFileName, ".jpg", storageDir);
}
```

Comment: Have you checked the more recent sample [code](https://bitbucket.org/gluon-oss/samples/src/master/GoNative/) and [documentation](http://docs.gluonhq.com/samples/gonative)?

Comment: Yes I did. Actually I'm using the `AndroidNativeService`.

Comment: Does it run for you? Both taking a picture or selecting a picture from the gallery should work fine

Comment: No it's not working, for the reasons I described. I installed the `GoNativeApp`on my phone, which is also not working

Comment: I've just tested it again, it works fine for me. I think you need 8.60.7 to be able to get the intent result with `FXActivity.getInstance().setOnActivityResultHandler()` (see [code](https://bitbucket.org/gluon-oss/samples/src/b05cde696279f4d2ceb330f374e4f1f36e58abe9/GoNative/src/android/java/com/gluonhq/gonative/AndroidNativeService.java?at=master&fileviewer=file-view-default#AndroidNativeService.java-51))

Comment: I've downloaded and installed the sample app again, using 8.60.7, without any success. So it seems to be a problem specific to my phone or android version 4.1.1